# Marketing a comics and artwork website

Tags: marketing

I've recently launched a comics website, but am having trouble getting it off the ground. I've seen other similar "marketing how-to's" questions, but none geared towards a pure content sharing website.

I've been using paid Facebook advertising as my primary means of gaining an audience, and growth has been nice and steady, but it's not getting me to where I want to be. The facebook page has 53k fans, but many of them aren't that engaged with my work, or post gibberish comments.

**In addition, I've tried tactics such as:**

- Improving SEO with proper meta tags, links, titles, and other techniques.
- Reaching out to local town and college newspapers

But those don't seem to be getting the attention I'd like... I feel like doing local things like that is futile if I want to gain the virality I'm looking for. I think the best way is to focus on SEO-related things and other web-marketing strategies.

Then I thought it might be because the content of the comics just isn't that funny... but everyone I've asked think they are good and wonder "hmm, not sure why more people aren't liking them".

**So, I am considering the following tactics:**

- Create a youtube video where I act out some of my comics (I feel like Youtube videos naturally gain a lot more attention than anything else)
- Post each new comic on all of the social sites- like reddit, 4chan, facebook, twitter, etc...
- Going around to local stores with flyers promoting the site
- I'm completely redesigning my site... many people have said it's far too "1990's". So I'm redesigning as such: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31704/how-to-not-make-my-website-have-a-1990s-look
- I will be adding liking & commenting to my site to drive traffic

Any ideas for a person in my shoes?